# Upload to bintray silently fails for AAR

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, bintray

I'm using [this](https://github.com/bintray/bintray-examples/blob/master/gradle-bintray-plugin-examples/android-gradle-3.0.0-maven-example/app/publish.gradle) example for android, but with my own details replacing the example ones

When I perform the task bintrayUpload

I get the following log,  even though it say success, there are no new files on bintray.

How can I debug this and find out why it failed?

```
    17:34:07: Executing task 'bintrayUpload'...

Executing tasks: [bintrayUpload]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Configuration(s) specified but the install task does not exist in project :components.
:components:bintrayUpload: file /Users/x/Dropbox/codes/androids/x/android/android/x-components/components/build/outputs/aar/components-release.aar.asc could not be found.
:components:bintrayUpload: file /Users/x/Dropbox/codes/androids/x/android/android/x/components/build/libs/components-0.2.6-javadoc.jar.asc could not be found.
:components:bintrayUpload: file /Users/x/Dropbox/codes/androids/x/android/android/x-components/components/build/libs/components-0.2.6-sources.jar.asc could not be found.
:components:bintrayUpload: file /Users/x/Dropbox/codes/androids/x/android/android/nx-components/components/build/outputs/aar/components-release.aar.asc could not be found.
:components:bintrayUpload: file /Users/x/Dropbox/codes/androids/x/android/android/x-components/components/build/libs/components-0.2.6-javadoc.jar.asc could not be found.
:components:bintrayUpload: file /Users/x/Dropbox/codes/androids/x/x/x/x-components/components/build/libs/components-0.2.6-sources.jar.asc could not be found.
:components:bintrayUpload
Uploading to https://api.bintray.com/content/true/x/components/0.2.6/x/x/x/components/components/0.2.6/components-0.2.6.aar...
Uploading to https://api.bintray.com/content/true/x/x/0.2.6/x/x/x/components/components/0.2.6/components-0.2.6-javadoc.jar...
Uploading to https://api.bintray.com/content/true/x/components/0.2.6/x/x/x/components/components/0.2.6/components-0.2.6-sources.jar...
Uploading to https://api.bintray.com/content/true/x/x/0.2.6/uk/x/x/x/components/0.2.6/components-0.2.6.aar...
Uploading to https://api.bintray.com/content/true/x/components/0.2.6/x/x/x/components/components/0.2.6/components-0.2.6.pom...
:bintrayPublish

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
17:34:09: Task execution finished 'bintrayUpload'.
```

Comment: Did you try to run the task with debug flag? `gradlew bintrayupload --debug`, it should get you all silent errors that were masked. And go through https://gist.github.com/miguelhincapie/7ca32d25561fc74b3d4c497758d597ed if it helps.

Comment: seem like something is wrong with :components module configuration... please post your build.gradle file from :components module... I suppose you forget to apply gradle android plugin in this module

Answer (score 0):

Gradle tasks run on daemon thread disable daemon thread using in gradle.properties file then try with --debug.

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
```